# Почему не корректно работает адаптивность слайдера Slick?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Использую слайдер Slick с настройкой adaptiveHeight: true . Проблема в том, что если в одном из слайдом добавлять динамически текст, то адаптивность начинает работать не корректно. 
Если нажать на первом слайде на кнопку show, то контент слайд не сжимается до размеров текста? Как решить эту проблему?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWWEva

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".slickNormalAdaptive").slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
$(".showItem").click(function(){
  $(this).prev("ul").find("li:nth-child(n+5)").toggleClass('hidden');
})

});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}


.slick-track {
  background-color: #484848;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slickNormalAdaptive">
  <div class="box100 green">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="showItem">Show</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box200 red">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="showItem">Show</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам slick очевидно не может отследить ваши изменения в css, поэтому ему нужно помочь, например задав опцию с аттрибутом refresh:

```
$slider.slick('slickSetOption', 'dots', true, true);
```

```js
$(function() {
  var $slider = $(".slickNormalAdaptive");
  $slider.slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
$(".showItem").click(function(){
  //$(this).prev("ul").find("li:nth-child(n+5)").toggleClass('hidden'); // есть способ и получше
  $(this).prev("ul").toggleClass('short-list');
  $slider.slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToShow', 1, true); //обновим slick
})

});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}


.slick-track {
  background-color: #484848;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
ul.short-list li:nth-child(n+5){
  display:none;
}
.slickNormalAdaptive {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slickNormalAdaptive">
  <div class="box100 green">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="showItem">Show</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box200 red">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="showItem">Show</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

по неясной причине в сниппете остается кусок следующего слайда, видимо это как-то связано с появляющимся и исчезающим вертикальным скроллом

Comment: В своем коде вы прописали .slickNormalAdaptive {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
А что если  количество элементов списка будет менятся или добавляться со временем, как тогда быть?

Comment: я просто оставил место под кнопочку справа, очень уж плохо выглядело.

Comment: извиняюсь, что-то затупил не правильно понял этот кусок кода)

Comment: Спасибо, большое, очень помог ваш ответ, уже несколько дней не мог решить эту проблему